# Always round up command

Tags: qgis, length, round-function

I have a problem with rounding numbers. I'm searching for a command that always rounds UP the length of a line to the next 0,1m. For Example I have a line with the length 56,12m I want to be rounded to 56,2m.

You know any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this expression with the function [`ceil()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#ceil) (rounds a number upwards). Multiply by 10, round it, then divide it by ten to get rounded up to the first digit:

```
ceil ("number"*10)/10
```

[image]